# scipy.misc.pilutil import imread works but still can't read in data

Tags: python, scikit-image, imread

I'm working through a tutorial and the code is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
from skimage import data
photo_data = misc.imread('foo.jpg')
```

This didn't work and stack overflow searches suggested I needed to install scikit-image. I installed it, but that still didn't work. More searching said I also need to install Pillow. Installed Pillow and that still didn't work.

More searching suggested I needed to write the code as:

```
import scipy.misc
from scipy.misc.pilutil import imread
```

No error from that (!) but then the code I to read in the photo doesn't work:

```
photo_data=misc.imread('foo.jpg')
```

error: module.scipy.misc has no attribute imread

if I try:

```
photo_data = misc.pilutil.imread('foo.jpg')
```

error is very ugly and talks about imread being deprecated and the errors are a LOT more complicated.

Is there is simple way to read this photo in?

Thanks.

Comment: Got it working! i installed the packages I thought I needed from the terminal, but I should have done it in Anaconda to make sure conflicts were resolved. So I un-installed and reinstalled everything correctly and what do you know - IT WORKS!

Comment: Since you already have skimage installed, I'd recommend using `from skimage import io; io.imread(...)` rather than  `scipy.misc.imread`.